# Accessing Java Privileged Actions from within Rhino script

Tags: java, javascript

How can I execute a local file from JavaScript running within Rhino in Java? I will consider any method that works from within the Rhino environment. My current exploration of the issue is below.

I am attempting this through java.lang.Runtime.exec, with help from the Mozilla "Scripting Java" tutorial i can access it. However this is a restricted action so calling it directly gives an access control exception.

To solve this I need to use the AccesController.doPrivileged method. An example of using this in Java is below;

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
          public Object run() {
             // Code goes here. Any permission checks within this
             // run method will require that the intersection of the
             // callers protection domain and the snapshot's
             // context have the desired permission.
          }
```

The road block is replicating the construction of a PrivilegedAction in javascript.

```
var ourRuntime = Packages.java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
//ourRuntime.exec("notepad.exe") //will raise Access Control Exception
var controller = Packages.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
var action = new Packages.java.security.PrivilegedAction(ourRuntime.exec("notepad.exe"))         // somehow make this wwrk
controller.doPrivileged(action)
```

[Mozilla Scripting Java](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html)

[java.securit.AccessController](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rhino is supported by Java 6 scripting [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/index.html), so you can wrap eval of your script with doPrivileged and execute entire script with necessary permissions. Example of java scripting API combined with doPrivileged is [here](http://worldwizards.blogspot.com/2009/08/java-scripting-api-sandbox.html)

Comment: This method should work but I'm wary of executing a whole script with Privileges, seems like bad practice.

Comment: @OutRideACrisis, you can of course have different privileges per script. Another way to achieve the OP's goal might be to use a URLReader and pass in a URL with a custom scheme (e.g., "scripts://"). Then, you could control access per script outside of code. Haven't tested this, but I think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success starting KWrite (for example) this way. I basically expose the Runtime object to the embedded JavaScript interpreter.

```
public class RunBasicScript {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Get a handle to the JavaScript context
    Context cx = Context.enter();

    try 
    {
        // Set up the standard JavaScript objects
        // like Object, Function etc.
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

        // Make Runtime.getRuntime available to our JavaScript code
        Object exec = Context.javaToJS(Runtime.getRuntime(), scope);
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "exec", exec);

        // Build our awesome script
        String script = "exec.exec('kwrite');";

        // Now we execute the script
        Object obj = cx.evaluateString(scope, script, "Testing", 1, null);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Error : " + e);
    }
    finally 
    {
        // We need to exit the Context.
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

}